# Command line: Copy files listed with DIR /S to another folder

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, cmd.exe

I'm trying to list all macro enabled files in my D: and copy them to a "newfolder" I created in the same drive, this is what I've tried and the error message:

```
D:\>copy dir \*.xlsm/S newfolder\
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What is the right syntax I should use?

Comment: The `copy` command you specified tries to copy a `dir` file in `\*.xlsm/S`, neither of which actually exist. Try using something like this (remove the `echo` when you're sure it's working fine): `for /r "D:\" %G in (*.xlsm) do echo copy "%~fG" "D:\newfolder\"`

Comment: that looks more complicated than I expected

Comment: This command would work: `copy *.xlsm newfolder`\ However, the `copy` command doesn't provide a `/s` parameter to scan subfolders.  If you were to parse the `dir` output, that would require a similar `for` command. As an alternative you can use `xcopy`, as shown by Tiramisu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### usually it would be:

D:> xcopy *.xlsm newfolder /s

BUT you cannot copy with option /s set if the target is within this path > cycling!

so the target directory has to be somehere else, not beyond the parent dir!

### example that would work:

xcopy d:\macros*.xlsm d:\newfolder /s

### or:

D:> xcopy \macros*.xlsm \newfolder /s

Comment: That copies the directory tree structure also, I can use that. To make a flat copy I finally used `D:\>for /r "d:\rubenbk" %G in ("*.xlsm") do copy %G "d:\rubentest"` which worked nicely.

Comment: Beware @Ruben, this can lead to trouble in case you have duplicate file names.